# How to create nested schema in mongoose

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I want to Create a Schema in mongoose. How to create for store only id i.e **"c.steam.at20l_chaxi.56951"**

```
"teams": {
            "c.steam.at20l_chaxi.56951": {
                "key": "c.steam.at20l_chaxi.56951",
                "players": [
                    "bsm_ayyappa",
                  
                ]
            },
            "c.steam.at20l_cpnxi.b1e2a": {
                "key": "c.steam.at20l_cpnxi.b1e2a",
                "name": "Champions XI",

                "players": [
                    "c.player.vamsi_krishna.d1944",
                    
                ]
            },
            "c.steam.at20l_kinxi.9479e": {
                "key": "c.steam.at20l_kinxi.9479e",
                "name": "Kings XI",
                "players": [
                    "c.player.m_lekhaz_reddy.ee44c",
                    "c.player.f_khadri.176fb"
                ]
            }
}
```

nested objects

Comment: What is exactly your question? Do you want to improve the schema? Set any field as `unique` into DB? Do a query for get... anythin? Please be clearer in your question.

Comment: please be clear with your question, that, you want to generate the ids also and store the ids with the nested objects also? , or you want the id to be created but the objects should be nested? .

Comment: i want to store these all teams